# All manual settings get wiped out when saved in My.cnf, why?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

When I open my.cnf to enter manual setting like:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 50M
innodb_log_file_size = 15M
bulk_insert_buffer_size=25M
log-slow-queries = mysql-inja-slow.log
```

All of my settings get vanished when I hit Save! My server has mysql  5.1.

Comment: What are you using to edit them?  What OS are you on? It sounds like it might just be a permission problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with :

chattr -i /etc/xxxx/x/x/my.cnf